# Node.js export to csv using - csv-express

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using npm "csv-express" package to export data to CSV. I'm having trouble getting the nested vendor name to display in the exported file. I used the $lookup (aggregation) to get the vendor name from another collection.

Here what the exported file look like:
[image]

Here is my query:

```
db.getCollection('systems').aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "sponsor": 1 } }, 
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "vendors",
        "localField": "vendorID",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "vendor"
      }
    }, 
    { "$project":{
        "sponsor":1,
        "address":1,
        "city":1,
        "state":1,
        "vendor.name":1
      }
    }])
```

Here's what the query returns:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab55fee294f2366c054d5eb"),
    "sponsor" : "John Doe",
    "address" : "123 Western Ave",
    "city" : "Los Angeles",
    "state" : "CA",
    "vendor" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "West Interactive"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the following but had no luck.

```
db.getCollection('systems').aggregate([
{ "$sort": { "sponsor": 1 } }, 
{ "$lookup": {
    "from": "vendors",
    "localField": "vendorID",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "vendor"
  }
}, 
{ "$project":{
    "sponsor":1,
    "address":1,
    "city":1,
    "state":1,
    "vendor.[0].name":1
  }
}])
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found [a great article](https://blog.couchbase.com/joining-nosql-documents-mongodb-query-language-vs-couchbase-n1ql/) on how to accomplish what I needed.

Here is update query:

```
db.getCollection('systems').aggregate([         
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "vendors",
        "localField": "vendorID",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "vendor"
      }
    }, 
    **{ $unwind: "$vendor" },**
    { "$project":{
        "sponsor":1,
        "address":1,
        "city":1,
        "state":1,
        **"vendorName":"$vendor.name"**
      }
    }])
```

This returned the data need for my export.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab55fee294f2366c054d5eb"),
    "sponsor" : "John Doe",
    "address" : "123 Western Ave",
    "city" : "Los Angeles",
    "state" : "CA",
    "vendorName" : "Acme Inc."
}
```